# Open MS Word in compare mode programatically

Tags: c#, ms-word, compare

I want to open two documents in compare mode programatically.

Something like:

```
Process.Start("winword.exe", string.Format("/n /compare \"Document.docx\" \"Document_V2.docx\""
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with COM automation interfaces.

See [_Application.CompareDocuments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.comparedocuments.aspx)

Comment: Can you make me a little example?... i just want to open Microsoft Word for the client.